# SageMaker can't access S3 when creating a labeling job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have an IAM role with the following permissions:

[image: permissions]

However when I try to create a labeling job in SageMaker and I click Create Labeling Job with:

- Manual data setup
- Copy-paste the IAM ARN
- Click browse S3

I don't see the files in the bucket. When I enter the s3:// path to the .jsonl file, I get this:

**NetworkingError: Network Failure - The S3 bucket 'cvat.mouseover.ai' you entered in Input dataset location cannot be reached. Either the bucket does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it. If the bucket does not exist, update Input dataset location with a new S3 URI. If the bucket exists, give the IAM entity you are using to create this labeling job permission to read and write to this S3 bucket, and try your request again.**

I also have CORS enabled for the bucket.

Comment: Which role did you add the permission to?

Answer (score 0):

You should check a region where you create Labeling Job. It must be the same as the region where bucket were created.